# Cannot check for null if the object is null ("cannot read the property" error)

Tags: javascript, null

I just cannot figure out how to solve a simple situation: when my JSON data returns an object where one of its properties is null, I just cannot find a way how to check for it, because even in the checking itself, the exception is thrown:

```
var data=Template.currentData();  //here the RECORD property is an empty string, ""

if(!data.record)   //throws an error, cannot read null of 'record'
```

How can I perform the check when I cannot get it to read the property at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
var data=Template?.currentData?.();

if(!data?.record)
```

Demo:

```js
const Template = "string without currentData property"

var data=Template?.currentData?.();

if(!data?.record){
  console.log("no record prop")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `data` value is not `null` before read the `record` value. So try this

```
if(data && !data.record)
```